# Undefined Index Laravel 4.0 - Possible Bug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, undefined-index

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here, so I hope I'm simply missing the obvious. Please find below exhibit a, my code including var_dumping:

```
$statuscheck = $read->readResponse();

$statusResponse = $statuscheck['StatusCheckResponse'];

echo "<pre>"; var_dump( $statuscheck, $statusResponse, $statuscheck['StatusCheckResponse']); die;
```

Which gives us the following results : [Here be the results](http://pastebin.com/hThPsXak)

That seems all normal right? Notice I've passed the **$statuscheck['StatusCheckResponse']** into the **$statusResponse** var and var_dumped them both. Both giving identical results in the above output.

But watch what happens when I take the **var_dump** away.

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6swO.png) a giant undefined index error! How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that code is inside a loop, or executed more than once on a single request, it could be a later iteration doesn't have the required indexes set.

Try replacing the **die** with this:

```
   if(empty($statuscheck['StatusCheckResponse'])) die;
```

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot for not looking for this. Thank you. Late night debugging not always the quickest way to resolve issues.